# Cocoa restrict window move area?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, firemonkey, firemonkey-fm2

I'm new to cocoa. 
I got an application in Windows with have MDI Child. Now i need to port it to MACOS. I known Mac doesn't have that kind of MDI Child so i try to set the child window can only move inside the main window only. Is that possible ?

Comment: Ew. Don't do that on OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible? Sure. Should you do it? No. The Mac does not have an MDI interface in the Windows sense, and you shouldn't try to fake it.

Ditch the parent window entirely. If there are toolbars or palettes in the main window, make them floating panels on the Mac. The child windows on Windows should simply be top-level windows on the Mac.

Comment: so i should not do it ? Still can't find a software that can be a UI Example to follow